# How to handle memory allocation error in Emscripten?

Tags: javascript, c++, new-operator, webassembly, emscripten

Is there simple way to hook memory allocation error in Emscripten (3.1.48 or maybe newer)?

Project built with no exceptions and C++ `operator new` calls C function `abort()` in this case.

Project build with pthreads which use JS Web Workers. We need to handle memory errors from main and others threads.

Project uses WebGL and canvas looks buggy on memory allocation error.

It is needed to separate error when no enough memory and others.

## I found only hacky solution which requires:

1. Adding `Module["onAbort"]` function which shows message (not simply JS `alert()`) but some HTML. `--pre-js` used for it. See https://emscripten.org/docs/tools_reference/emcc.html#emcc-pre-js
2. For Web Workers we can't modify DOM tree for our HTML message. So we need to use `postMessage/onmessage` API and modify DOM in main thread using `worker.onmessage`. Emcripten already has this functionality for `"onAbort"` and some others https://github.com/emscripten-core/emscripten/blob/e967e20b4727956a30592165a3c1cde5c67fa0a8/src/library_pthread.js#L307 So we can call `postMessage({ cmd: "callHandler", handler: "onAbort", args: ["Some error text"] })` inside `Module["onAbort"]` when we are inside worker and it calls `Module["onAbort"]` again but in main thread.
3. Next part is to decide was `abort()` called because of memory exhaust or other way. This information exists in `Module.stackTrace()` string and we can find substring `".wasm.operator new"`. This works fine for Debug builds
4. For Release build where .wasm and .js files are optimized and no debug information I only find that stack trace contains `".wasm:wasm-function[214]"` which points to `operator new`. We can get information that 214 means `operator new` using `--emit-symbol-map` (see https://emscripten.org/docs/tools_reference/emcc.html#https://emscripten.org/docs/tools_reference/emcc.html). This requires some additional script which will find index of `operator new` and modify resulting .js file.

This solution works fine but implementation doesn't looks fine.

Also it does not handle situation when `malloc()` returns `nullptr` but I don't think that this case can be handled easily.

It is possible to override `operator new` and even `malloc` but this can be not easy to do because using of third party libraries. Also it can impacts to performance.

Hooking of exceptions in `window.onerror` can helps but looks like it does not contains information about was error because of `operator new` or not.

I'm expecting that Emscripten or `WebAssembly.Memory` have some easy way to handle memory errors.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Given your requirements, I think that best option would be to simply implement a `malloc` wrapper and do whatever you need to do.